# how to store print_r data

Tags: php, arrays

I want to reuse the print_r result so I try to store result again. it's possible ?

> array list

```
<?php

          $books =  array(

              "phil" => array("my girl" => 2.5, "the god delusion" => 3.5,
                              "tweak" => 3, "the shack" => 4,
                              "the birds in my life" => 2.5,
                              "new moon" => 3.5),

              "sameer" => array("the last lecture" => 2.5, "the god delusion" => 3.5,
                                "the noble wilds" => 3, "the shack" => 3.5,
                                "the birds in my life" => 2.5, "new moon" => 1),



          ?>
```

> recommend function

---

> show results

```
require_once("recommend.php");
require_once("sample_list.php");


$re = new Recommend();
$hi = print_r ($re->getRecommendations($books, "tom"));

$out = array($hi);
print_r ($out);

?>
```

Comment: Why store the value of `print_r`? Just store the array and then use `print_r` when needed.

Comment: Through the recommend function, the result will be dynamic. so than , i want save it to do recommendation.

Comment: but i miss the recommend function part....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the second argument with `true`, it will store the result as string (you could use `echo` to print) and does not print.

```
$re = new Recommend();
$hi = print_r ($re->getRecommendations($books, "tom"), true);
```

Example:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$result = print_r($arr, true);
```

`$result` output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Other possibility is use [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) the output it's a little different

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$result = var_export($arr, true);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it this way

`$hi = $re->getRecommendations($books, "tom");`

`print_r ($hi);`